# Can we always scale a star-shaped region of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology

> **Question.** Let $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset which is star-shaped about $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there always a continuous function
>   $$f:V\to(0,\infty)$$
>   such that the scaling map
>   $$\varphi:V\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad \varphi(x)=f(x)x$$
>   is a homeomorphism?

I know a couple of examples. For instance
$$\varphi:B_1(0)\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad \varphi(x)=\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}x$$
is a homeomorphism from the unit ball to $\mathbb{R}^n$. It seems that we can always scale $V$ in that way, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: rays starting at $0$ - $R_v = \{ tv\,|\, t\in \mathbb R^+\}$ where $v\in\mathbb R^n$. They are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^+$. What is their intersection with $V$ homeomorphic to?

Comment: @Ennar That doesn't mean that we can fit these to form a continuous map.

Comment: You are right, this is problematic, but if you impose more restrictions on the $V$, the proof should be the same as for bounded convex sets. For example, $V$ is bounded, open, and each ray intersects boundary of $V$ at precisely one point.

Comment: Consider the union of the open disk about $0$ and the open half-plane $\{y > 0\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$.